# Why no timeout support in std::lock?

Tags: c++, c++11, locking

If I want to grab multiple locks without running the risk of deadlock, I can use the `std::lock` function:

```
int data1, data2;
std::mutex m1, m2;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(m1, std::defer_lock);
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(m2, std::defer_lock);

std::lock(lock1, lock2);           // guaranteed deadlock-free

// work with data1 and data2
```

But what if I want to acquire the locks within a specified period and timeout otherwise?  Is there a reason there is nothing like `try_until` for locks that's akin to `wait_until` for futures and condition variables?

Comment: @Nicol: What's wrong with passing deferred locks? `std::lock` accepts any kind of lockable and you won't have to worry about unlocking later on.

Comment: @Nicol: From the C++11 standard (30.4.3/4): "Each template parameter type shall meet the Lockable requirements, [ Note: The unique_-
lock class template meets these requirements when suitably instantiated. —end note ]"

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Oh, right. Nevermind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why no timeout support in std::lock?

1. Because no one proposed it.
2. Because this area was so controversial that the less proposed, the more likely to get it accepted.
3. Because we were afraid that if we standardized everything, you would get bored.
4. It was left as an exercise for the reader.

Hmm... I'm running out of ideas... :-)

Oh!

It is easy for you to do yourself if you need it:

**Update**

Here's a rewrite I like better:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

template <class Clock, class  Duration, class L0, class L1>
int
try_lock_until(std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> t, L0& l0, L1& l1)
{
    std::unique_lock<L0> u0(l0, t);
    if (u0.owns_lock())
    {
        if (l1.try_lock_until(t))
        {
            u0.release();
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

template <class Rep, class  Period, class L0, class L1>
int
try_lock_for(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> d, L0& l0, L1& l1)
{
    return try_lock_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + d, l0, l1);
}


int main()
{
    std::timed_mutex  m1, m2;
    try_lock_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50), m1, m2);
}
```

As Anthony suggests, feel free to propose this.  Also feel free to just use it, and let us know if it was actually useful or not.

Answer (score 11):

`std::timed_mutex` has `try_lock_until` and `try_lock_for` member functions. However, you are right that there is no equivalent of `std::lock` with a timeout.

Locking a mutex with a timeout is only of use in particular niches. Locking multiple mutexes with a timeout was not something anyone felt strongly enough about to propose, so it isn't in C++11.

The standards committee is currently actively seeking proposals for the next standard. If you feel that a timeout-aware equivalent of `std::lock` is valuable, why not write a proposal?